# PHP/PDO can't bind 'TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE' values

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm trying to prepare and execute a query against my PostgreSQL database using PHP's PDO library, and it isn't working as expected.

When using the command line `psql` client, the following works as one would expect:

```
=> SELECT TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2013-01-01 00:00:00';

      timestamp      
---------------------
 2013-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

However, I don't seem to be able to do the same using PHP/PDO. The following code:

```
<?php
try
{
    $db = new PDO(...);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE ?;");

    $stmt->bindValue(1, "2013-01-01 00:00:00", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    echo $row[0];
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Produces the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SELECT TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE $1; ^
```

I am aware of PostgreSQL's `to_timestamp()` function, which **does** work, but it returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` instead - the problem being that `to_timestamp` isn't an immutable function (i.e., to not return different results based on the sever's timezone configuration).

Similarly, binding the following does what I want, and can be prepared successfully:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;
```

But I'm hoping for something cleaner / less verbose.

Am I simply preparing my statement incorrectly or, if this will never work, what is an alternative way to go from a string in my application to a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting it directly, with parenthesis to avoid confusing PDO/Postgres:

```
(?)::timestamp
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Thanks! I'm tempted to file a bug against PDO - or is the syntax `timestamp '2013-01-01 00:00:00'` not *intended* to work for some reason?

Comment: I'm unsure it's intended to work without an explicit cast operator, and even then you might still need parenthesis in Postgres and other adapters (would need to try to verify, and I'll confess I haven't.)